# Conditional expectation of the number of dice rolls

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X$ number of points for a random roll of a six-sided die. I need to find $E(X|(X −2)^2)$. My attempt was the following.
By definition $E(X|(X −2)^2) = E(X|\sigma((X-2)^2))$, where $\sigma((X-2)^2)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on random variable $(X-2)^2$. The conditional mathematical expectation in the discrete case has the formula:
$$
E(X|\sigma) = \sum_{n\in N}\frac{E(X\mathbb{I}_{D_{n}})}{Pr(D_n)}\mathbb{I}_{D_n}
$$
where $\left\{D_n\right\},n\in N$ is a disjoint partition of the $\sigma$-algebra. We can see that random variable $(X-2)^2$ can take values {0, 1, 4, 9, 16} with probabilities:
$$
Pr((X-2)^2 = 0) = Pr((X-2)^2 = 4) = Pr((X-2)^2 = 9) = Pr((X-2)^2 = 16) = \frac{1}{6}\\
Pr((X-2)^2 = 1) = \frac{1}{3}
$$
Consider $D_0 = \left\{0\right\}, D_1 = \left\{1\right\}, ..., D_{16} = \left\{16\right\}$. This will be a partition of $\sigma((X-2)^2)$. Then by the formula above we get:
$$
E(X|(X-2)^2) = \sum_{n\in \left\{0, 1, 4, 9, 16\right\}}\frac{E(X\mathbb{I}_{D_{n}})}{Pr(D_n)}\mathbb{I}_{D_n} = \frac{21}{6}*6 + \frac{21}{6}*3 + \frac{21}{6}*6 + \frac{21}{6}*6 + \frac{21}{6}*6 = \frac{189}{2}
$$
But i'm not sure about my solution. Is this solution right?\

Probably i made a mistake while counting expectation $E(X\mathbb{I}_{D_n})$. This expectation should be equal:
$$
E(X\mathbb{I}_{D_0}) = \frac{2}{6}, E(X\mathbb{I}_{D_4}) = \frac{4}{6}, E(X\mathbb{I}_{D_9}) = \frac{5}{6}, E(X\mathbb{I}_{D_16}) = 1, E(X\mathbb{I}_{D_1}) = \frac{2}{3} 
$$